# Can't convert base64 images from csv to file in Python

Tags: python, csv, base64

I know it looks like it has been answered before, but I can't seem to find a solution for this issue. I have a CSV file that contains very long strings of Base64 encoded images (~5mb each). I enabled the CSV field size limit to max. There are several of the images decoded separated by columns then a few values that are only a couple of words long. I can read these through print(row[7]) for example no problem. The images won't print the base64 strings, and i'm trying to decode them and save them to the filesystem but they end up being empty. Any thoughts?

```
 fh = open("~path~/image.png", "wb")
            x = base64.b64decode(row[1])
            fh.write(x)
            fh.close()
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Works now. CSV split on python seems to act a little different than in Java. The empty values came up due to the csv being saved differently than the exporting tool I used indicated, so it was left with values ("8",,"data:image/png;base64,IR0BRR....",...). I didn't catch the empty space before, which is why it was showing blank, and then I also attempted to append the data:image/png part to the beginning of itself since I believed that python string split would split the comma after base64 like Java would. After adjusting for this, the image correctly saves in my filesystem.

Comment: "Empty" means that the PNG-file has `0` bytes?

Comment: Correct! I believe that maybe it isn't an issue with the writing to the file, but rather the retrieval of the value from CSV

Comment: Adding one or more `print`s (or using a debugger) may help to be sure. With this you can also find out e.g. the value of `row` with `print(repr(row))`.

Comment: Could you using something like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to upload a couple of rows of your CSV file to and then paste a link to it here? It would then be possible to recreate the problem.

Comment: I can't quite share the csv data, but I can give you an example of what it looks like:    76, data:image/png;base64,IVB0R......, data:image/png;base64,IVB0R......

Comment: So I decided to try running it in java instead to see if that would change. For one the string splits on the comma after the base64. I tried all combinations of creating a byte array from just the stuff after and both combined, but no luck. Python doesn't give me an error, but Java throws a IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 22 error

Comment: Looks like I got it to work, will edit the original post. Kind of a stupid error on my part, but thanks guys!